# Div with jQuery Issue

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to do that if I click on this:

```
<div class="dec qtybutton" data-id="{{ $item->id }}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></div>
```

It displays an alert to know that it really works, my jQuery code is this one:

```
$('.dec').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

The thing is that I have tried all this and it has not worked:

```
$('.dec').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});


$('.dec > i').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

I do not know how to do that this jquery reads the .dec i or the .dec then if I push it does not do anything, it does not display the alert.. so I wonder what is the problem? because it has not worked at all.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the full HTML code or at least try to reproduce it here, you code works fine, where did place the javascript in the HTML? are you using jQuery once the document is ready?

Comment: @ROOT yes when it's ready, and I have other jquries working I think that it's that it does not recognize the DOM, but I do not know how to do that part that it recognizes that.

Comment: It is working fine for me (Actually `i` does not have any `data` attribute). Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) for us.

Comment: does your browser console has any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , In jquery you can directly access `data` attribute.

```js
$(".dec").click(function(){
let id = $(this).data('id');
alert(id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dec qtybutton" data-id="2">click<i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></div>
```